# IS NULL in CASE in predicates

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case, isnull

tell me pls, that's real - use the CASE construct, where the expression with IS NULL/IS NOT NULL will be returned in TNEN?
I have a procedure in a package that receives an input parameter and it is passed to the selector in cursor, which I want to set one of the predicates:

```
  select t1...
         t2...
  from test t1,
       test t2
  where t1.flg = 'N'
  AND t2.field = 'supertest'
  AND CASE 
            WHEN input_parm = 'Y' THEN t1.id IS NOT NULL
            WHEN input_parm = 'N' THEN t1.id IS NULL
            WHEN input_parm IS NULL THEN
            ELSE t1.id = input_parm
            END
```

input_parm - is the parameter entering the procedure

- if input_parm=Y then the t1.id field is not equal null
- if input_parm=N then the t1.id field is equal null
- if input_parm is null then this this condition should not be taken into condition, those selector should be both from IS NULL and IS NOT NULL
- if input_parm IS NOT NULL and !='Y' and !='N' then t1.id=input_parm

In the example the compiler swears at IS NULL after THEN. Can you help me plz?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The predicates of a `CASE` expression (i.e. what follows `THEN` and `ELSE`) must be literal values, not boolean expressions.  You may refactor your `CASE` expression as:

```
AND
    (input_parm = 'Y' AND t1.id IS NOT NULL) OR
    (input_parm = 'N' AND t1.id IS NULL) OR
    input_parm IS NULL OR
    t1.id = input_parm
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, th's what I need

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to use `AND/OR` but if you really want to use the `CASE..WHEN` then you can use the following:

```
    CASE
        WHEN INPUT_PARM = 'Y'
             AND T1.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        WHEN INPUT_PARM = 'N'
             AND T1.ID IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN INPUT_PARM IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN T1.ID = INPUT_PARM THEN 1
    END = 1
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree construction AND/OR will be better